# pkg-config cannot find a customized build of a library

Tags: g++, pkg-config

I installed ffmpeg4.2 through `apt` a week ago. The library was installed under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Then I realize that I want to test my code in ffmpeg4.5, so I built it from source and installed it under `/home/xxx/ffmpeg_build/lib`. I also did `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/xxx/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

However, pkg-config cannot find the ffmpeg4.5 that I want it to see. So I checked the pc_path variable with `pkg-config --variable=pc_path pkg-config`, and it gave me `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig`.

I am guessing that pkg-config goes to /usr/local to find the `*.pc` file and therefore ignore my customized build. Is there a way I can append my customized path in the front, so as pkg-config can find the ffmpeg4.5 I built from source first?

**EDIT:**
I just recall that pkg-config can find the ffmpeg4.5 I built from source correctly at first, but I did  `ldconfig -v` for OpenCV setting, and then it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final work around is to decode all configs from the *.pc files into a g++ command manually. It's definitely not ideal, but for a small project I am working on, it does what I need

Answer (score 0):

Add you custom lib to the dyanmic linker search path.

1.) add a new conf file

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/customlib.conf
```

2.)
insert: (assuming your lib is in the directory /usr/local/ffmpeg45/lib

```
/usr/local/ffmpeg45/lib
```

3.) run

```
ldconfig -v 2>&1|grep -iv ffmpeg
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hannes, but it didn't work for me. ffmpeg is bundle of libaraies which are named all differently (libavfilter, libcodec, libswscale, etc), I don't know if I should add all those libraries independently to make it work.